# UITextField start at end of text

Tags: iphone, focus, uitextfield

I have a `UITextField` that displays a long text string. The problem is that when I first open the view containing the `UITextField`, it automatically shows the end of my text; I want it to show the beginning.

I read the `UITextField` Class Reference on the Apple dev center, but nothing seems to allow me to change it. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

`UITextField` does not support this. You might consider switching to `UITextView` (which has a `scrollRangeToVisible:` method).